# using the collatz sequence in dictionaries

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to python and currently, I'm trying to learn dictionaries. I'm trying to write a program that asks the user for a number, and then outputs the number less than or equal to the one the user entered with the longest Collatz sequence.

This is what I currently have right now, but I don't know why it won't work.

```
def collatz(number):
    segLength = {}
    for i in range(1, number + 1):
        current = 1
        count = 0
        while current != 1:
            if current % 2 == 0:
                current = number / 2
            elif current % 2 != 0:
                current = (3 * number + 1) 
            count += 1
        segLength[i] = count
    value = list(segLength.values())
    key = list(segLength.keys())
    x = max(value)
    index = value.index(x)
    output = key[index]
    return output
    
result = collatz(number)
print = result
```

Comment: `print = result` should be `print(result)`

Comment: BTW, you can get the key with the maximum value with `output = max(segLength, key=lambda k: segLength[k])`

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration of your for loop, you set `current = 1`, so `current != 1` will always be `False` and you'll skip the `while`.

It looks like you want to calculate the collatz sequence for each number so I'm guessing you want to instead set `current = i`.

Then, for each iteration of your for loop, `current` will have the number you want to reduce to 1 and count the number of steps it takes. To make this work, you'll want to change:

```
current = number / 2
```

(and the corresponding 3n+1 line in the elif) to

```
current = current / 2
```

because `number` is always going to be the number you passed into the function at the start, not the number you're trying to run a collatz sequence on this iteration

It looks like it should work otherwise!

EDIT: you should also call print rather than assign to it as Barmar said.